# Как решить ошибку pygame.error: File is not a Windows BMP file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Я работаю на Mac и недавно наткнулся на такую ошибку: pygame.error: File is not a Windows BMP file . Я последовал инструкциям отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25120883/how-to-uninstall-pygame-on-mac-osx-10-9-4, но все еще ничего :(

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   

File "/Users/[username]/Downloads/Pygame_project/extra/list_textures.py", line 5, in <module>
    
just_left = pygame.image.load("textures/player/left_1.png")    pygame.error: File is not a Windows BMP file
```

Уже неделю ломаю голову над этой ошибкой помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: В какой момент выходит ошибка - во время инсталляции, во время работы программы?

Comment: во время инсталляции

Comment: Ошибка говорит что ожижается bmp, а вы png грузите. Или вы не ту библиотеку для изображений используете, или png кодек не подключен, или конвертируйте png в bmp.